# iPhone (And iTunes) shows 1GB of photos, but I don't have any

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photos

iPhone 5S, running iOS 8.0.2. For some reason, I've got 1GB of photos that show up on my iPhone and in iTunes, but I can't delete them. I used iPhoto to sync them off my phone. I also had iPhoto delete them.

When I go into photo albums, it's empty. So, how can I delete them?

Comment: "Photos" and "Albums" are two separate tabs in the Photos app in iOS 8 (and also "Shared"). Have you checked in all of them?

Comment: @MikeScott Post a answer with that - there is a album called "Recently Deleted" - I went in there, deleted all of them, and it freed the space.

Comment: i got same problem .... its bcos of new feature Recently Deleted Photos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WT3Z0Hals4 .... see this video ... explains this problem in iOS 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in "Albums" as well as "Photos" and you should find your photos.